# Best way to handle this HttpWebRequest in a For loop?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

**Question Background:**

I am making a call to Amazon's Product Advertising API. This gives back X number of paged results at a time with an node in the XML stating how many pages are available i.e 10. A page number is then specified and the API will responsed with the results for that given page.

**Question:**

I want to add all of the results from each page to a list that I then send to an MVC view. Currently I'm doing this through a For Loop specifying the upper limit as the maximum number of loops, for example if there are 10 pages available I'm looping round page 1, 2, 3, 4......and so on until 10.

The following code shows how the request is currently being made. Is this ok? It works but I have seen a `StackOverflow` exception a couple of times when debugging.

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
          {
                string requestUrl = "http://amazonApi.com/page"+i;

                WebRequest amazonRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

             try
             {
                WebResponse response = amazonRequest .GetResponse();

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = doc;

                //Add Xml Document to List.....
                AddToList(xmlDoc);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + e.Message);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Just briefly, your for loop will only run 9 times. Change the condition to i<=10. I would use a Using block for the creation and disposal of the WebRequest. If the request to page 5 fails the code will continue to execute and just skip out the results from page 5, I assume that's the desired effect?

Comment: You could maybe even change your for loop to a parallel for; that is if you're not fussed about the order in which your items appear. It would spawn off a few threads and cut execution down fairly drastically (maybe by 3 to 4 times or more depending on processor count)